# SpamAssassin sending legit emails to spam, despite sender being whitelist

Tags: spam, spamassassin

I can not for the life of me figure out why emails from a "white-listed" sender are still getting very high scores from SpamAssassin and not being delivered.

The email headers are:

```
From orders.usa@theirsite.com Wed Apr 25 10:52:26 2012
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.1 (2010-03-16) on
    www.mysite.com
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-**107.9** required=5.0 tests=AWL,BAYES_00,HTML_MESSAGE,
    KHOP_DYNAMIC,MIME_QP_LONG_LINE,**USER_IN_WHITELIST,USER_IN_WHITELIST_TO**
    autolearn=ham version=3.3.1
Received: from webaccess.theirsite.com (webaccess.theirsite.com [81.246.110.67])
    by www.mysite.com (8.14.4/8.12.8) with ESMTP id q3PHqPpR019683
    for <alison@mysite>; Wed, 25 Apr 2012 10:52:26 -0700
X-Envelope-To: <alison@mysite.com>
Received: by webaccess.theirsite.com (Postfix, from userid 1001)
    id DA5E64223F; Wed, 25 Apr 2012 19:52:21 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from beovpzardb1.theirsite.local (65.110-246-81.adsl-static.isp.belgacom.be [81.246.110.65])
    by webaccess.theirsite.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id B1C794218A
    for <alison@mysite.com>; Wed, 25 Apr 2012 19:52:21 +0200 (CEST)
Subject: RE: questions about garbage cans
From: =?utf-8?Q?Orders_USA?= <orders.usa@theirsite.com>
To: =?utf-8?Q?alison=40eefaco=2Ecom?= <alison@mysite.com>
Date: Wed, 25 Apr 2012 19:51:11 +0200
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
 boundary="=_fC3CzCFWmN93q8ZWTzGby0LlKwQH2gYGeZlQzD+NmoGVrVuE"
In-Reply-To: <005701cd22e7$e79eb4a0$b6dc1de0$@com>
References: <005701cd22e7$e79eb4a0$b6dc1de0$@com>
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
X-Mailer: Zarafa 7.0.6-32752
Sender: =?utf-8?Q?S_Danner?= <s.danner@theirsite.com>
Message-Id: 
 <zarafa.4f98398f.1ba8.4a80d64c7fe5d835@beovpzardb1.theirsitea.local>
X-Copyrighted-Material: Please visit http://www.theirsite.com
```

Any help here is greatly appreciated :)

From /var/log/maillog

```
Apr 25 10:52:26 www sendmail[19683]: q3PHqPpR019683: from=<orders.usa@theirsite.com>, size=15656, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<zarafa.4f98398f.1ba8.4a80d64c7fe5d835@beovpzardb1.theirsite.local>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=webaccess.theirsite.com [81.246.110.67]
Apr 25 10:52:26 www spamd[8985]: spamd: connection from localhost [127.0.0.1] at port 56915
Apr 25 10:52:26 www spamd[8985]: spamd: setuid to mail succeeded
Apr 25 10:52:27 www spamd[8985]: spamd: processing message <zarafa.4f98398f.1ba8.4a80d64c7fe5d835@beovpzardb1.theirsite.local> for mail:8
Apr 25 10:52:27 www spamd[8985]: spamd: clean message (-107.9/5.0) for mail:8 in 0.7 seconds, 15956 bytes.
Apr 25 10:52:27 www spamd[8985]: spamd: result: . -107 - AWL,BAYES_00,HTML_MESSAGE,KHOP_DYNAMIC,MIME_QP_LONG_LINE,USER_IN_WHITELIST,USER_IN_WHITELIST_TO scantime=0.7,size=15956,user=mail,uid=8,required_score=5.0,rhost=localhost,raddr=127.0.0.1,rport=56915,mid=<zarafa.4f98398f.1ba8.4a80d64c7fe5d835@beovpzardb1.theirsite.local>,bayes=0.000000,autolearn=ham
```

What Sendmail is doing

```
Apr 25 10:52:26 www sendmail[19683]: q3PHqPpR019683: from=<orders.usa@theirsite.com>, size=15656, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<zarafa.4f98398f.1ba8.4a80d64c7fe5d835@beovpzardb1.theirsite.local>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=webaccess.theirsite.com [81.246.110.67]
Apr 25 10:52:27 www sendmail[19855]: q3PHqPpR019683: to="|/etc/mail/jprocess alison@mysite.com", ctladdr=<alison@mysite.com> (8/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=prog, pri=45901, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

Comment: This question is not programming realated and is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Anders, Thanks for your reply. The question is, however, related to programming as SpamAssassin requires programming, or reprogramming to achieve what I need.

Comment: Give the -107.9 score, did you check /var/log/maillog to see what the delivery failure is?

Comment: @cjc, thanks for taking a look. Ironically, thats where I was headed when I read your post. The maillog is just as cryptic as the headers:

Comment: @cjc - Edited original post to include references from maillog

Comment: OK, the queue entry for Sendmail is q3PHqPpR019683.  Do a `grep q3PHqPpR019683 /var/log/maillog`.  The spamd messages aren't actually interesting at this point: we need to see what Sendmail does after spamd processes.

Comment: @cjc - Thanks again for your help here :) I again updadated the the original post to include what Sendmail is doing after spamd.

Comment: So, what's "/etc/mail/jprocess" ?  Sendmail says it's sent it to that.  From Sendmail/SpamAssassin's point of view, the mail was fine, it's been passed through to the next step.  If the mail is missing, then that jprocess thing is eating it.  Does it have a log?

Comment: @cjc - Good call!!! I looked into 'jprocess' and it is a small program for directing mail to the appropriate box, or to the appropriate forward location. In that script, I found a line "$mailbox = $SPAM_ACCOUNT if $bad_message_id_flag == 1;"  So, I have commented out that line to see if the emails from this sender will get through. I'll update once a test message has been sent. Thanks for your logical approach and for helping :)

Comment: Just to note, your approach feels like a weird, non-standard way to hook up SpamAssassin into Sendmail.  The "right" way would be to use something like Amavis-ng or a milter (e.g., spamass-milter).  Anyway, should I write up my comments as an Answer, and you can accept it?

Comment: @cjc - Ok, I managed to get the emails to go through :)  Sure, if you want to write it as an answer, I would be happy to accept it!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

So the score is -107.9 (negative one hundred and seven point nine).  That's very, very, **very** low, certainly less than the 5.0 threshold for spam.  I assume the asterisks are added by you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I did add the ** (had hoped it would bold that text)  And, I hadn't noticed the - in front of the score. So, the score is extremely low, but the emails are still not going through. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm really sorry, no clue.

Answer (score 3):

The process for figuring out why mail isn't getting delivered is to examine the complete lifecycle of the message as it works its way through the MTA, antispam, antivirus, etc., rather than focusing just on the antispam aspect.  This involves looking at `/var/log/maillog` from the message's receipt to its final delivery.

The OP's mail log shows message q3PHqPpR019683 being received by Sendmail, which then  passes it to `spamd` for SpamAssassin scoring.  SpamAssassin assigns it a very negative score, which would be expected for a whitelisted sender.  The message is then returned to Sendmail for further processing.  Sendmail then successfully hands off the message (with "stat=Sent") to a shell script: `to="|/etc/mail/jprocess alison@mysite.com"`.  From the point of view of Sendmail (and SpamAssassin), the message was successfully accepted, scored, and handed over to the next phase in the process, so the issue isn't with SpamAssassin.

The OP's examination of the `/etc/mail/jprocess` script showed a possible issue with how it handles marked mail before passing the message to the MDA.  Modifying that script allowed test messages to successfully be delivered.

Note that the jprocess script seems to be non-standard.  The more "accepted" way of doing this is to use something like Amavis-ng or a Sendmail milter.  The OP may want to investigate those options.